# I need to design a system to send real time notification to mobile device with a large database

Tags: php, cron, push-notification

I have a push notification sending system written in PHP-5.4 which is used to send push notifications over the mobile devices with a fix time interval. I need to make it quick as much as possible. Right now this thing is executing via a schedule manger (cron).

Right now all the things are working fine because number of application users is not too much. But in existing system the speed of execution and delivery time of notification will be decreased with the increasing of users.

> execution speed & response time ∝ 1 / number of users

What i want to implement now...

- Notifications must be sent instantly
- This server can be triggered from another server remotely whenever needed.
- Execution speed & response time should not be effected drastically on the continuous increasing of users
- Server should work as a cron server also and other servers should not be effected due to the processes executed on this system because there is a single database is running for them.

In short i want rebuild/upgrade my existing non stable system to a efficient and stable server which will not affect by the number of users.

---

*Any suggestion or help is appreciated*
Thanks

Comment: Ever heard about [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)? They are used for these type of applications. For PHP, you may try [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use multiprocessing and avoid cron jobs.

Have a look [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/1/3). It's basically using PHP forks to generate "multithreading".

Also, create daemons (all-time running processes) instead of cron jobs. You'll end up with more "real-time". Actually not that hard to implement. [Guide](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2014/06/02/how-to-create-a-php-linux-daemon-service/)

The more users you have, more threads you create.

Enjoy the reading!

Comment: Thanks Carlos.  
In case of php mutli-threading mechanism, should i go with pthreads extension. I have only a single doubt about it and that is the stability of this extension.

Comment: @Vikas pcntl_fork works fine. Make sure you have a perfect logic for your children, and no problems at all. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php